# Programming trouble Action listeners-FillRect

Tags: java, action

I am attempting to recreate the game Mastermind in Java GUI format.  my trouble stems from the actionlistener not being able to access my NewPanel class i think. Any help would be great, im really stuck on this.

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Mastermind extends JFrame {
        public Mastermind(){
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
            add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(p2, BorderLayout.EAST);

            /* PANEL 1 LAYOUT STUFF*/
            JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
            JPanel p5 = new JPanel();

            JButton red = new JButton("RED");
            JButton blue = new JButton("BLUE");

            JLabel HTP = new JLabel("How To Play");
            JLabel htp =new JLabel("<html>Player 2 will have 10<br> "+
                "attempts to correctly<br> guess Player 1's<br> "+
                "Password.The<br> password will consist<br> "+
                "of a 4 length sequence<br> "+
                "of 4 different colors.<br> "+
                "Colors may be used<br> "+
                "more than once or<br> "
                "not at all.</html>");
            htp.getForeground();
            JLabel results = new JLabel("Guesses:");

            p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p5.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

            p1.add(p4, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            p1.add(p5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            p1.add(results, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            p4.add(HTP, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            p4.add(htp,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            p5.add(red);
            p5.add(blue);
            red.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));

            /* END PANEL 1 LAYOUT STUFF*/

            /* PANEL 2 LAYOUT STUFF*/


            JPanel p3 = new JPanel();

            JButton green = new JButton("GREEN");
            JButton yellow = new JButton("YELLOW");

            p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));


            p2.add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


            p2.add(new NewPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            p3.add(green);
            p3.add(yellow);



            /* END PANEL 2 LAYOUT STUFF*/

            /* ACTION LISTENER EVENTS */        
            red.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fillRect(Color.red);
                }
            });

            blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }
            });

            green.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }
            });

            yellow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                }
            });
}

/* END ACTION LISTENER EVENTS */

public static void main(String[] args) {
            Mastermind frame = new Mastermind();

            frame.setTitle("Mastermind");
            frame.setSize(334, 500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
class NewPanel extends JPanel {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int x,y;

        for(y = 10; y<= 330; y+=35){
            for(x =10; x<=120; x+=35 ){
                g.drawRect(x, y, 25, 25);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the boxes to change color depending on the button. I don't know where you want to take it from here but this should be a good start.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Mastermind extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    NewPanel p1,p2,p3,p4,p5;
    public Mastermind(){
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p1 = new NewPanel();
        p2 = new NewPanel();
        add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.EAST);

        /* PANEL 1 LAYOUT STUFF*/
        p4 = new NewPanel();
        p5 = new NewPanel();

        JButton red = new JButton("RED");
        JButton blue = new JButton("BLUE");

        JLabel HTP = new JLabel("How To Play");
        JLabel htp =new JLabel("<html>Player 2 will have 10<br> "+
            "attempts to correctly<br> guess Player 1's<br> "+
            "Password.The<br> password will consist<br> "+
            "of a 4 length sequence<br> "+
            "of 4 different colors.<br> "+
            "Colors may be used<br> "+
            "more than once or<br> " +
            "not at all.</html>");
        htp.getForeground();
        JLabel results = new JLabel("Guesses:");

        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p4.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p5.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        p1.add(p4, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.add(p5, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p1.add(results, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        p4.add(HTP, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p4.add(htp,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        p5.add(red);
        p5.add(blue);
        red.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));

        /* END PANEL 1 LAYOUT STUFF*/

        /* PANEL 2 LAYOUT STUFF*/


        p3 = new NewPanel();

        JButton green = new JButton("GREEN");
        JButton yellow = new JButton("YELLOW");

        p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));


        p2.add(p3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        p2.add(new NewPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p3.add(green);
        p3.add(yellow);

        red.addActionListener(this);
        blue.addActionListener(this);
        yellow.addActionListener(this);
        green.addActionListener(this);    

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("RED")){
            p1.setRectColor(Color.red);
        }else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("BLUE")){
            p1.setRectColor(Color.blue);
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("GREEN")){
            p1.setRectColor(Color.green);
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("YELLOW")){
            p1.setRectColor(Color.yellow);
        }
        p1.updateUI();
        p2.updateUI();
        p3.updateUI();
        p4.updateUI();
        p5.updateUI();
    }
}



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

class NewPanel extends JPanel {
    private Color c;
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(this.c);
        int x,y;

        for(y = 10; y<= 330; y+=35){
            for(x =10; x<=120; x+=35 ){
                g.drawRect(x, y, 25, 25);
            }
        }
    }
    public void setRectColor(Color c){
        this.c=c;
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;    

public class testRect{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mastermind frame = new Mastermind();

        frame.setTitle("Mastermind");
        frame.setSize(334, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i should replace all JPanels with the newPanel class?

Comment: this is not homework, though i did get the idea from another forum.  im new to gui and it sounded like a fun project to try